# Scroll Bar/Paging for a table in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am working with SSRS 2008 and want to add pagination or scroll bar to the "Table" control which displays my error records. Please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up getting the solution that there is no way to have scroll bar or pagination for a table in the SSRS 2008.